# PayPal Payments - HTTP Response code 400

Tags: php, exception, paypal, error-handling

I'm workin on PayPal Payments in PHP. Everything was fine until i got this error:

**Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.**

It's thrown when I try to create method for my payment: $payment->create($api);

```
<?php

use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException;

require '../src/start.php';

$payer = new Payer();
$details = new Details();
$amount = new Amount();
$transaction = new Transaction();
$payment = new Payment();
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();


// Payer
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');



// Details
$details->setShipping('2.00')
->setTax('0.00')
->setSubtotal('20.00');

// Amount
$amount->setCurrency('GBP')
->setTotal('22.00')
->setDetails($details);

// Transaction
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
->setDescription('Membership');


// Payment
$payment->setIntent('sale')
->setPayer($payer)
->setTransactions($transaction);

// Redirect urls
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl($myReturnUrl)
->setCancelUrl($myCancelUrl);

$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);

try {

$payment->create($api);


} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Why this is happening? How can I fix that? How eventually I can get more detailed exception message?

Comment: Can you please follow the sample code provided here: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html

Comment: you can get detailed exception message by doing $e->getData();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Amount
$amount->setCurrency('GBP')
->setTotal('22.00')
->setDetails($details);
```

And make sure also your paypal business account whats your primary currency in my case it worked fine with changing the value from 'GBP' to 'USA'

```
// Amount
$amount->setCurrency('USA')
->setTotal('22.00')
->setDetails($details);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$api = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
        new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential('Your Client ID',' Secret')
      );
```

Make sure you have provided that right values